# Deleting all array values from a specific offset and on

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has 120~ or so offsets and I was wondering how you would delete all the values of said array after a certain offset containing a specified string. For example: Offset [68] has the string 'Overflow'. I want to remove everything including 68 and beyond and rebuild the array (with its current sorting in tact).

I tried messing around with slice and splice but I can't seem to get it to return the right values. I was also thinking of just grabbing the offset number that contains `'Overflow'` and then looping it through a for statement until `$i = count($array);` but that seems a little more intensive than it should be.

Would this be the best way? Or is there some function to do this that I'm just using wrong?

Comment: Why isn't [`array_slice`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$desired = array_slice($input, 0, $upTo);
```

Comment: Oh. array_slice worked fine. I just didn't realize that some of my offsets were unset, so I was getting issues with my array because of the missing offsets [0][2][6] etc. It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the string occurrence in the array, and, if the value was found, trim the array from that point;

```
function removeString($string, $array)
{
  # search for '$string' in the array
  $found = array_search($string, $array);

  if ($found === false) return $array; # found nothing

  # return sliced array
  return array_slice($array, $found);
}
```

And if you need to make the array sequential (to avoid surprises due to missing offsets), you can always add in the first line `$array = array_values($array)`. This will reorganize the array values in a new array with ordered offsets: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...